# Extracting JSON value from a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, json-extract

I have data which is of type json in mysql and column name is 'student_data'. student_data:

```json
{
  "STUDENT_HISTORY": [
    {
      "regno": "12345678",
      "UPDATE_DATE_UNIX_TIME": "65667"
    },
    {
      "regno": "12345332",
      "UPDATE_DATE_UNIX_TIME": "654333"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to extract student_data based on condition where regno = "12345678" and here I have only regno value don't know index in json and I have tried json_extract query also which is given below.

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(student_data,"$.STUDENT_HISTORY.regno") 
  FROM student table 
 WHERE STUDENT_HISTORY.regno = "12345678"
```

Comment: Format your question - it is unreadable now. Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Show desired output in textial table-formatted form. Specify precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `json_table()`:

```
select s.*, x.*
from student s
cross join json_table(
    s.student_date,
    '$.STUDENT_HISTORY' columns (
        regno varchar(50),
        UPDATE_DATE_UNIX_TIME varchar(50)
    )
) x
where x.regno = '12345678'
```

Comment: Getting syntax error  'ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',UPDATE_DATE_UNIX_TIME varchar(50))) x where x.regno ='12345678' at line 1
'

Answer (score 0):

You still can use `JSON_EXTRACT()` with some little changes such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM student 
 WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`student_data`,'$.STUDENT_HISTORY[0].regno'))='12345678'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=10a7dc8514510a9204f2a3ea86b21d31)</kbd>

Comment: we need a query which is not based on index. it should be generalized. regno = ' 12345678'  only we knew this value. we don't know index in json.

Comment: @NeelaKandan well, you should explain the logic in the question explicitly then

Comment: yes, most probably if have added another json in my question, understanding would be better let me edit it.